# Empty array when textfield value changes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, textfield

It's working perfect if i enter a string for the first time. But then if i try to change it it doesn't work as the nameArray is adding all the values in index. I tried emptying the array writing namArray = [ ];   after     $("#Code").val([ ]); but it makes the nameArray length 1 after every change in Name textfield & i'm not getting my result. This is my Code.

```
var nameArray = [];
var count;
var i;    

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Name").on('input', function () {                                                    

        $("#Code").val([]);


        var getName = $("#Name").val();                       

        nameArray.push(getName);                

        if (nameArray.length >= 3) {
            count = 3;
        }
        else if (nameArray.length <= 3) {
            count = nameArray.length;
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            $('#Code').val(nameArray[i]);
        }

    });   

});
```

I just want to clear the nameArray if there's a change in textfield so that it can take new changed string from textfield & work thereby.

Comment: So clear the array.  You are not doing that.  `$("#Code").val([]);` has zero effect on `nameArray`

Comment: When exactly do you want to clear the array?

Comment: I want to clear the array after the Name textfield value changes.

Comment: Changes how?  You are capturing the input event that will happen any time the user adds or removes a displayable character to/from the value.  When, exactly, do you want to clear it out completely?

Comment: Are you simply wanting the code to match the first (up to) three characters of the name?

Comment: @Taplar yes i want that. 
If a user adds a string for the first time it's working & i don't need to clear my nameArray at this moment. But if he changes his string like write a new name i want my nameArray to be changed then as it should work like it works for the first time user adds string

Comment: I do not understand how this is "working the first time".  Your logic is pushing to the array the value of the input **every single time a character changes**.  And then at the end, your for loop is iterating over elements 0-3 (a max of the first 4 elements in the array), and setting the value to the nameArray[3] element once your array meets or exceeds 4 entries.  I do not understand what logical conditional you are wanting to check for to know that the "changed".  You are setting the value to the first 4 characters of the name, so the use of the array seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Taplar how can i solve this problem then? I want that Code textfield to exact with Name textfield with 3 to 4 characters. Any suggestion?
And i'm sorry that i couldn't make it clear to you.

Comment: The answer I posted below grabs the first (up to) 4 characters.

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? When it's done the value of `#Code` will be `nameArray[count]`, so why not just set that value once?

Comment: Also, `nameArray[count]` will often be undefined, since array indexes go from 0 to count-1.

Comment: I messsed it up. But this problem is solved by @Taplar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the code to the first 4 characters of the name.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Name").on('input', function () {
        $("#Code").val(this.value.substring(0, 4));
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" id="Code" placeholder="Code">
```

Comment: working as expected. Sorry i didn't know that it can be done so easily. Thanks to you.

Comment: @SaifAyon  No problem.  I just wanted to make sure I understood what you wanted, :)